# webpack-dev-server incremental build very slow

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr, webpack-2

When I follow the `angular2-webpack-starter` (https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) instructions, I am running into some severe performance issues during incremental builds when running the following command:

`npm run server:dev:hmr`

The initial build only takes about 30 seconds, however, if I touch one of the files in order to kick off an incremental build update, it takes longer than the initial build!

[image: Log asset optimization]

This delay gets much worse as I add content to my app, exceeding 2 minutes just for the 'asset optimization' part.

I have tried changing the `devtool` option to no effect.

Here is some env info:

- Windows 7 Pro, 64-bit
- angular2-webpack-starter@5.0.5
- node v4.4.3
- npm 3.10.2